# How can I use the latest router v6 navigate in a hoc to navigate

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am learning React and I have this HOC and would like to instead of returning `null` it should return the "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.0" navigate to another page like :

```
navigate('/someOKPage', { replace: true });
```

**The HOC:**

```
/* eslint-disable react/prefer-stateless-function */
import React from 'react';
import AuthUserContext from './context';

const WithAuthorization = condition => Component => {
    class withAuthorization extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
                    {authUser => (condition(authUser) ? <Component {...this.props} /> : null)}
                </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
            );
        }
    }

    return withAuthorization;
};

export default WithAuthorization;
```

I have tried to do this but can't find a way. Should I do this in the render, or make some function?

I tried this but get hook error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component

```
const WithAuthorization = condition => Component => {


class withAuthorization extends React.Component {
        onChange = event => {
            const navigate = useNavigate();
            navigate('/', { replace: true });
        };

        render() {
            return (
                <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
                    {authUser => (condition(authUser) ? <Component {...this.props} /> : this.onChange())}
                </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
            );
        }
    }

    return withAuthorization;
};
```